# NavigationLink label: View has a menu button but it has to be long pressed

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have NavigationLink inside a Scrollview that links to a detailView that then displays more information to the user. My labelView has a small ellipses menu in the bottom corner to do things like assign as favourite or delete the item etc (a bit like Apple News). If I tap the menu button then I get sent to the detailView. I have to hold the menu button down to activate it.

Is it possible to simply tap the menu button with out getting sent to the DetailView?

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            Group {
                if events.isEmpty {
                    NoEventsView()
                } else {
                    ScrollView {
                        ForEach(events) { event in
                            NavigationLink(
                                destination: EventDetailView(event: event),
                                label: {
                                    EventView(event: event)
                                        .padding(.horizontal)
                                        .padding(.vertical, 2)
                                }
                            )
                            .buttonStyle(.plain)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
struct EventView: View {
    
    @Environment(\.modelContext) private var modelContext
    @State var counter = false

    let secondTimer = Timer.publish(every: 10, on: .main, in: .common).autoconnect()
    var event: Event

    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            title
            timeStamp
            Line()
                .stroke(style: StrokeStyle(lineWidth: 0.5))
                .frame(height: 1)
                .opacity(0.1)

            HStack {
                timeElapsed
                Spacer()
                
                Menu {
                    Button {
                        withAnimation {
                            event.favourite.toggle()
                        }
                    } label: {
                        HStack {
                            Text("Favourite")
                        }
                    }
                    Text("Edit")
                    Section {
                        Button(role: .destructive) {
                            withAnimation {
                                modelContext.delete(event)
                                try? modelContext.save()
                            }
                        } label: {
                            HStack {
                                Text("Delete")
                                Image(systemName: "trash")
                            }
                        }
                    }
                } label: {
                    Image(systemName: "ellipsis")
                        .frame(width: 30, height: 30)
                        .imageScale(.large)
                        .foregroundColor(.gray)
                }
            }
            .padding(.top, -6)
            .padding(.bottom, -14)
        }
    }
}
```

[NavigationLink menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ckfa9.png)

I can only get the menu to drop down if I long press the ellipses button. as a tap on it sends me to the NavigationLink DetailView. Is there a way to specify where can be tapped in a navigationLink?

I have tried a few different NavigationLink implementations but I still get the same result

Comment: I would suggest moving the menu out of the NavigationLink, and instead place it on top, perhaps using `overlay`.